# Flash coding problem

Tags: php, flash, character-encoding

I got some information in my Flash application from a php script. Flash displayed it as: `Radioart=Mia Frejman - Ett hjÃ¤rta - Ett HjÃ¤rta`

The string contain some Swedish symbols. How I can output this normally?

best
Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the output of your php script is not utf-8, the default encoding for flash.

Radioart=Mia Frejman - Ett hjÃ¤rta - Ett HjÃ¤rta is the latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) representation of the utf-8 string: Radioart=Mia Frejman - Ett hjärta - Ett Hjärta.

So make sure that the php outputs everything correct in utf-8 your flash will display it correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an encoding problem.  I had the same issue while parsing an xml file in flash.  The problem was the the xml file had not been save in utf-8.  Perhaps you should:

1. Check your php encoding
2. Check the encoding of your text editor
3. Is the data coming from a database?  Check your database encoding

Answer (score 0):

Your database connection might also be the problem. 
You can check encoding of your connection by running the script:

```
echo mysql_client_encoding($db);
```

And set it by

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $db);
```

(in case you are running MySQL of course)

Answer (score 0):

That's an UTF-8 stream as it would be represented in ISO-8859-1. You may use ByteArray to decode UTF-8 into a string on the client side, if you can't figure out any other way to do this. This snippet seems to do the Right Thing(tm).

```
var ba: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var receivedData: String = "Mia Frejman - Ett hjÃ¤rta - Ett HjÃ¤rta";
for (var i: uint = 0; i < receivedData.length; i++)
    ba.writeByte(receivedData.charCodeAt(i));
ba.position = 0;
var decodedString: String = ba.readMultiByte(ba.length, "UTF-8");
```